# Running Application on SIM808 GNSS module beside it's internal firmware

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, gps, gsm, gnss

I'm trying to load my written program to SIM808 and the module will be responsible for running my program and also its internal firmware. 
SIMCOM has a document about doing this in SIM800 module but there are not any equivalent for SIM808. Does SIM808 support this ability?

Comment: Did you ask SIMCOM representative?

Comment: They do not replied me yet.